# How to get the link to the file after uploading to Google Drive via api?

Tags: php, laravel-5, google-drive-api, google-cloud-datastore

I am following this guide. I am able to upload images to my google drive but I am not able to get the path to the file.

https://gist.github.com/ivanvermeyen/cc7c59c185daad9d4e7cb8c661d7b89b

```
// Get img that was uploaded to my server
$img = request()->file('img');

// Save that image to my google drive
Storage::disk('google')->put('img.png', fopen($img, 'r+'));

// ?? how do I get the path to the file so I can save it in my database?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked it up in the laravel documentation?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#file-urls

For your code you should use this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$url = Storage::disk('google')->url('img.png');

dd($url);
```

Comment: The img.png is only the name of the file. So if I do that then it will just save an empty file. The file is the $img, And Im saving it as img.png

Comment: To get the url you should use the name of the file, what's wrong with that? Have you tried it? maybe add a `dd($url)` after the last line